# Failed to create object. Many-To-Many relation

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I have a problem with my code. It's about a restaurant. I have two objects with a Many-To-Many relation: Products and Days. When I try to create a Day, I receive this error: "Failed to create object: App\Entity\Day\Day". Where am I wrong?

I put the code for entities here. If you need more just tell me. I don't think that it is from admin part.

Here is the Product entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Product;

use App\Entity\Category\Category;
use App\Entity\Day\Day;
use App\Entity\ProductEntry\ProductEntry;
use App\Entity\Restaurant\Restaurant;
use App\Entity\Schedule\Schedule;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * Class Product
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Product\ProductRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="products")
 * @package App\Entity\Product
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="added_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $addedDate;

    /**
     * @var boolean
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="availability", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    private $availability;

    /**
     * @var Category
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category\Category", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="category_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;

    /**
     * @var float
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="float", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $price;

    /**
     * @var ProductEntry
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\ProductEntry\ProductEntry", mappedBy="originalProduct", cascade={"persist"})
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     */
    private $productsEntries;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Schedule\Schedule", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="schedule_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @var Schedule
     */
    private $schedule;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Restaurant\Restaurant", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="restaurant_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     *
     * @var Restaurant
     */
    private $restaurant;

    /**
     * @var Day
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Day\Day", mappedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $days;

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name ?: "";
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->addedDate = new \DateTime();
        $this->days = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $description
     */
    public function setDescription(string $description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAddedDate()
    {
        return $this->addedDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $addedDate
     */
    public function setAddedDate($addedDate)
    {
        $this->addedDate = $addedDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAvailability()
    {
        return $this->availability;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $availability
     */
    public function setAvailability($availability)
    {
        $this->availability = $availability;
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    public function getPrice()
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    /**
     * @param float $price
     */
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $this->price = $price;
    }

    /**
     * @return Category
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * @param Category $category
     */
    public function setCategory($category): void
    {
        $this->category = $category;
    }

    /**
     * @return ProductEntry
     */
    public function getProductsEntries()
        {
        return $this->productsEntries;
    }

    /**
     * @param ProductEntry $productsEntries
     */
    public function setProductsEntries(ProductEntry $productsEntries): void
    {
        $this->productsEntries = $productsEntries;
    }

    /**
     * @return Schedule
     */
    public function getSchedule()
    {
        return $this->schedule;
    }

    /**
     * @param Schedule $schedule
     */
    public function setSchedule(Schedule $schedule): void
    {
        $this->schedule = $schedule;
    }

    /**
     * @return Restaurant
     */
    public function getRestaurant()
    {
        return $this->restaurant;
    }

    /**
     * @param Restaurant $restaurant
     */
    public function setRestaurant(Restaurant $restaurant): void
    {
        $this->restaurant = $restaurant;
    }

    /**
     * @return Day
     */
    public function getDays()
    {
        return $this->days;
    }

    /**
     * @param Day $days
     */
    public function setDays(Day $days): void
    {
        $this->days = $days;
    }
}
```

Here is Day entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity\Day;

use App\Entity\Product\Product;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Day
 * @package App\Entity\Day
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\Day\DayRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="days")
 */
class Day
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="current_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $currentDate;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="max_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    private $maxDate;

    /**
     * @var Product
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product\Product", inversedBy="days", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_day",
     *     joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="day_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="product_id", referencedColumnName="id")})
     */
    private $products;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @param int $id
     */
    public function setId(int $id): void
    {
        $this->id = $id;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $name
     */
    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getCurrentDate()
    {
        return $this->currentDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $currentDate
     */
    public function setCurrentDate(\DateTime $currentDate): void
    {
        $this->currentDate = $currentDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function getMaxDate()
    {
        return $this->maxDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param \DateTime $maxDate
     */
    public function setMaxDate(\DateTime $maxDate): void
    {
        $this->maxDate = $maxDate;
    }

    /**
     * @return Product
     */
    public function getProducts()
    {
        return $this->products;
    }

    /**
     * @param Product $products
     */
    public function setProducts(Product $products): void
    {
        $this->products = $products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure about your namespaces ? I guess your files are in the folder Entity, did you create subfolders ?

Comment: I have subfolders with the name of entities. The last path in namespace is a folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you created a column for your Day Entity that is called `current_date`

```
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="current_date", type="datetime", nullable=false)
     */
    private $currentDate;
```

If you are using MySQL, `current_date` is a reserved word. Please check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html for further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Like Vincent said in comment, your namespaces are fishy...
Unless you really placed them in a sub-folder, it should be `namespace App\Entity`

In Product entity you can shorten you `JoinColumn` for some parameters.
Unless you really need something specific, you don't need to write that much. Symfony have 'default' values.
Also, you don't add `@var` on a mapping. Symfony will take is as a parameter only instead of mapping.

```
/**
 * @var Category
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Category\Category", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE", nullable=true)
 */
private $category;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Schedule\Schedule", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $schedule;
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Restaurant\Restaurant", inversedBy="products", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $restaurant;
```

The same apply to your Day entity.

```
/**
 * @var Product
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Product\Product", inversedBy="days", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="product_day")
 */
private $products;
```

Doing so will prevent you to make some smalls mapping errors.

Try to correct those points first, then let us know if you still have your problem.

Comment: It didn't work. I have subfolders in Entity. It's App\Entity\Product and there in Product subfolder is a Product.php file

Comment: I see... May you state why you made sub-folders in your question @DragosBrindusescu ? I think many of us will wonder about it. Also, just in case, did you update your SQL schema after this change?

Comment: The problem was name of variables. I was using MySQL and there are some reserved words that I was using them for my properties.